# How to find h-index in microsoft academic?

Tags: bibliometrics

I am wondering how do we find h-index here:
http://academic.research.microsoft.com/

Comment: it was there on the old version of MAS. Now they removed it and put total citations instead. I really recommend not to check MAS since updates are very slow compared to Google Scholar. I have published a paper in a conference (indexed by MAS) almost three years ago and its still does not show up in their website. As an alternative, http://arnetminer.org is fairly updated with h-index while GScholar rocks at this matter.

Comment: @seteropere regarding arnetminer.org, it seems very specialized (although I don't know in what field)… definitely not a generic tool, unlike Google Scholar or Microsoft Academic

Comment: [Publish or Perish](http://www.harzing.com/pop.htm) is a very handy application to dig all the data on the web about an author. It report h-index, g-index and a bunch of other influence factors.

Answer (score 3):

The h-index was removed from Microsoft Academic Search in January 2013, according to the [features update list](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/About/Help.htm) (which, not surprisingly, is the first Google result for “h-index Microsoft Academic Search”).